# Create Sqlalchemy ORM class from regular class gets "has no attribute ''_sa_instance_state''"

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a game that I am coding for school (not a project or homework) and I am trying to use a SQLite database with sqlalchemy to store the game info. I have the classes `Student`, `Class` and `Grade`. Each student has a unique code that can identify them. This is the code for the school models, most of it is irrelevant to this problem

```
# school.py

import typing as t

class Student:

    def __init__(self,
                 first_name: str,
                 surname: str,
                 middle_names: t.Sequence[str] = None,
                 clazz: t.Optional = None,
                 code: t.Optional[str] = None):
        if middle_names is None:
            middle_names = []
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_names = middle_names
        self.surname = surname

        self._full_name = None

        self.code: t.Optional[str] = code
        self.target: t.Optional[Student] = None
        self.is_dead: bool = False
        self.has_killed: bool = False

        self.clazz: t.Optional[Class] = clazz
        if isinstance(self.clazz, Class):
            self.clazz.add_student(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        if self._full_name is None:
            self._full_name = f"{self.first_name} "
            if self.middle_names:
                self._full_name += f"{' '.join(self.middle_names)} "
            self._full_name += str(self.surname)
        return self._full_name


class Class:
    def __init__(self, grade_name: str, class_name: str, students: t.Optional[t.Dict[str, Student]] = None,
                 grade: t.Optional = None):
        self.class_name = class_name
        self.grade_name = grade_name
        self.name = self.grade_name + self.class_name

        self.student_dict = {} if students is None else students

        self.grade: Grade = grade

    def add_student(self, student: Student):
        if student.clazz is None:
            student.clazz = self
        self.student_dict[student.full_name] = student

    def remove_student(self, student: Student):
        for name, _student in self.student_dict.copy().items():
            if _student == student:
                self.student_dict.pop(name)
                return
        raise ValueError(f"{student} is not in the class")

    @property
    def students(self) -> t.List[Student]:
        return list(self.student_dict.values())

    @staticmethod
    def _sort_key(student: Student):
        split = student.surname.split()
        return (
            split[-1],
            ' '.join(split[:-1])
        )

    def sort(self, key=None) -> None:
        key = key or self._sort_key
        self.student_dict = dict(sorted(self.student_dict.items(), key=lambda x: key(x[1])))


class Grade:
    def __init__(self, grade: int, classes: t.Optional[t.Dict[str, Class]] = None, school: t.Optional = None):
        self.grade_num = grade

        self.class_dict: t.Dict[str, Class] = {} if classes is None else classes

        self.school = school

    def add_class(self, clazz: Class):
        if clazz.grade is None:
            clazz.grade = self
        self.class_dict[clazz.name] = clazz

    def remove_class(self, clazz: Class):
        for name, _clazz in self.class_dict.copy().items():
            if _clazz == clazz:
                self.class_dict.pop(name)
                return
        raise ValueError(f"{clazz} is not in the class")

    @property
    def classes(self) -> t.List[Class]:
        return list(self.class_dict.values())

    @staticmethod
    def _sort_key(clazz: Class):
        return (
            int(clazz.grade_name),
            clazz.class_name
        )

    def sort(self, key=None) -> None:
        key = key or self._sort_key
        self.class_dict = dict(sorted(self.class_dict.items(), key=lambda x: key(x[1])))

    @property
    def students(self) -> t.List[Student]:
        students = []

        for clazz in self.classes:
            students.extend(clazz.students)

        return students

    def rsort(self, key=None) -> None:
        key = key or self._sort_key
        for clazz in self.classes:
            clazz.sort()
        self.sort(key)


class School:
    def __init__(self, name: str, grades: t.Optional[t.Dict[str, Grade]] = None):
        self.name = name

        self.grade_dict: t.Dict[str, Grade] = {} if grades is None else grades

    def add_grade(self, grade: Grade):
        if grade.school is None:
            grade.school = self
        self.grade_dict[str(grade.grade_num)] = grade

    @property
    def grades(self) -> t.List[Grade]:
        return list(self.grade_dict.values())

    @staticmethod
    def _sort_key(grade: Grade):
        return grade.grade_num

    def sort(self, key=None) -> None:
        key = key or self._sort_key
        self.grade_dict = dict(sorted(self.grade_dict.items(), key=lambda x: key(x[1])))

    @property
    def students(self) -> t.List[Student]:
        students = []

        for grade in self.grades:
            students.extend(grade.students)

        return students

    def rsort(self, key=None) -> None:
        key = key or self._sort_key
        for grade in self.grades:
            grade.rsort()
        self.sort(key)
```

What I would like is to create sqlalchemy ORM classes based off these regular classes. I wrote this but I get an error.

```
# db.py

import typing as t

import school
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Student(school.Student, Base):
    __tablename__ = "students"
    code = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    middle_names = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    is_dead = Column(Boolean)
    has_killed = Column(Boolean)

    target_code = Column(String, ForeignKey('students.code'))
    target = relationship("Student", remote_side=[code])

    clazz_name = Column(String, ForeignKey("classes.clazz"))
    clazz = relationship("Class", back_populates='students')

    def __init__(self, first_name: str, surname: str, middle_names=None,
                 clazz: t.Optional[school.Class] = None, code: t.Optional[str] = None, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(middle_names, str):
            middle_names = middle_names.split(',')
        super().__init__(first_name, surname, middle_names, clazz, code)
        cls_ = type(self)
        for k in kwargs:
            if not hasattr(cls_, k):
                raise TypeError(
                    "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" % (k, cls_.__name__)
                )
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Student):
            return all((
                self.code == other.code,
                self.first_name == other.first_name,
                self.middle_names == other.middle_names,
                self.surname == other.surname,
                self.target == other.target,
                self.is_dead == other.is_dead,
                self.has_killed == other.has_killed,
                self.clazz == other.clazz,
            ))
        return False

    def short_eq(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Student):
            return all((
                self.code == other.code,
                self.first_name == other.first_name,
                self.middle_names == other.middle_names,
                self.surname == other.surname
            ))
        return False


class Class(school.Class, Base):
    __tablename__ = "classes"
    clazz = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    students = relationship("Student", back_populates="clazz")

    grade_name = Column(String, ForeignKey("grades.grade"))
    grade = relationship("Grade", back_populates="classes")

    def __init__(self, grade_name: str, class_name: str, students: t.Optional[t.Dict[str, Student]] = None,
                 grade: t.Optional = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(grade_name, class_name, students, grade)
        cls_ = type(self)
        for k in kwargs:
            if not hasattr(cls_, k):
                raise TypeError(
                    "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" % (k, cls_.__name__)
                )
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])


class Grade(school.Grade, Base):
    __tablename__ = "grades"
    grade = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    classes = relationship("Class", back_populates="grade")

    def __init__(self, grade: str, classes: t.Optional[t.Dict[str, Class]] = None, school: t.Optional = None):
        super().__init__(grade, classes, school, **kwargs)
        cls_ = type(self)
        for k in kwargs:
            if not hasattr(cls_, k):
                raise TypeError(
                    "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" % (k, cls_.__name__)
                )
            setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])


def add_student(session: Session, student: Student):
    if None in (student.clazz, student.code):
        print("Bad")
        return
    check = (
        session.query(Student)
        .filter(Student == student)
        .filter(student.clazz == Student.clazz)
        .filter(student.clazz.grade == Student.clazz.grade)
        .one_or_none()
    )
    if check is not None:
        print(check)
        return

    grade = (
        session.query(Grade)
        .filter(Grade == student.clazz.grade)
        .one_or_none()
    )
    if grade is None:
        session.add(student.clazz.grade)

    clazz = (
        session.query(Class)
        .filter(Class == student.clazz)
        .one_or_none()
    )
    if clazz is None:
        session.add(student.clazz)

    session.add(student)

    session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_path = "test.db"
    engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db_path}")
    Sess = sessionmaker()
    Sess.configure(bind=engine)
    session = Sess()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    grade = school.Grade(12)
    clazz = school.Class('12', 'A')

    students = [
        Student("Name1", "Sname1", clazz=clazz, code='aa7'),
        Student("Name2", "Sname2", clazz=clazz, code='bb7'),
        Student("Name3", "Sname3", clazz=clazz, code='cc7')
    ]

    grade.add_class(clazz)

    print(students)
    for student in students.values():
        add_student(session, student)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coding/Python/assassin_game/db.py", line 167, in <module>
    Student("Name1", "Sname1", clazz=clazz, code='aa7'),
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 433, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 430, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "D:/Coding/Python/assassin_game/db.py", line 33, in __init__
    super().__init__(first_name, surname, middle_names, clazz, code)
  File "D:\Coding\Python\assassin_game\school.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.clazz: t.Optional[Class] = clazz
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 279, in __set__
    self.impl.set(
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1024, in set
    value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1046, in fire_replace_event
    value = fn(
  File "C:\Users\Scott\.virtualenvs\assassin_game-NMk6Zdxg\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1456, in emit_backref_from_scalar_set_event
    instance_state(child),
AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

I don't know what the problem is or how I can fix it. Or is there just a way better method of doing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see the answer to your other question, i believe the reason for this is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66885146/99594